# How to store value of enum in arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, enums

I have an `enum` like this:

```
public enum SomeEnum 
{
    ENUM_VALUE1("Some value1"),
    ENUM_VALUE2("Some value2"),
    ENUM_VALUE3("Some value3");
}
```

I need to store values of `enum` **Some value1**, **Some value2** and **Some value3** in an `ArrayList`.

I can get all values in an array using `SomeEnum.values()` and iterate over that array and store the value in an `ArrayList` like this:

```
SomeEnum values[] = SomeEnum.values();
ArrayList<SomeEnum> someEnumArrayList = new ArrayList<SomeEnum>();
for(SomeEnum value:values) 
{
    someEnumArrayList.add(value.getValue());
}
```

Is there any other method like `values()` that returns array of **Some value1**, **Some value2** and **Some value3**?

Comment: Just use `Arrays.asList(values)` which returns a list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could build that list inside the `enum` itself like this:

```
public enum SomeEnum {

    ENUM_VALUE1("Some value1"),
    ENUM_VALUE2("Some value2"),
    ENUM_VALUE3("Some value3");

    private static final List<String> VALUES;

    private final String value;

    static {
        VALUES = new ArrayList<>();
        for (SomeEnum someEnum : SomeEnum.values()) {
            VALUES.add(someEnum.value);
        }
    }

    private SomeEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static List<String> getValues() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(VALUES);
    }

}
```

Then you can access this list with:

```
List<String> values = SomeEnum.getValues();
```

Comment: How to check the Arraylist of enum contains value or not ?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Java 8 and cannot change the enum:

```
List<String> list = Stream.of(SomeEnum.values())
                          .map(SomeEnum::getValue)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create list from array like this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(SomeEnum.values());
```

Comment: This will return a ```List``` though, not an ```ArrayList```. ```List```s aren't implementing all methods, e.g. ```remove``` won't work.